# Paypal set wrong Content-Type what to do?

Tags: soap, paypal

Our Paypal payments are broken and the problem is a wrong Content-Type we get from them, should I go and make some fix on my side or hope they have in their staff someone who will catch this and fix it?

```
curl -I https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened an internal issue about this, but it is likely that you'll be able to fix your side much sooner.

Comment: Thank you. We decided today to migrate to the Rest API as we catch out in the mean time Reference transactions are supported there too.